# SQL Server 2012 server role

Tags: sql-server-2012

In my SQL Server 2012 I have created a server role. I would like the server role can alter just one database one the server because I have many database on the server. How can I grant access for alter data in one database on the server?

Thank you in advance,

Nico.

Comment: by 'alter data' you mean administration or even insert/upadate/delete data?

Comment: for insert/update/delete data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have just added the login to the server.  Unless you have given the login `sysadmin` (I presume you have not), you will need to individually set the security **per database** ie. map the user to the database, e.g.

```
USE [Database]
GO

CREATE USER [User] FOR LOGIN [User] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

You will need to add the user to Security/Users in the actual database folder.  If you want them to read/write data into/from existing tables, give them `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` by right clicking and going to Properties -> Membership.  If you want them to be able to create/drop objects in the database e.g. tables, they also need `db_owner`.   They only have the rights for that db.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of what TJB said, please document on : https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ms178569.aspx